# Creating a custom Filter Webpart in SandBox? How-To?

Tags: web-part, filter, sandbox-solution

Since a little while now I've been trying to create a custom filter webpart in Sandbox. So far, it seems that all the usual ways to create a custom filter webpart programatically ina farm solution are not available in Sandbox.

Has anyone already created a custom filter webpart in Sandbox or know a good place to direct me to get the answers I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Webpart connections are not allowed in sandbox solutions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615464.aspx